# Java Splitting String with keywords

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am having problems in splitting the following string.

```
String str = "eat big mac .at East MacDonald .from onwards";
```

I want the result to be in

```
[ eat big mac, .at, East MacDonald, .from, onwards]
```

I can't split by space or dot, is there any way I can split into that?

Comment: If you want to split on spaces, why aren't the first three words split up? The last two were split however...

Comment: What are the exact criteria that would yield such a result? Or is that your question?

Comment: those strings with dot at front are keywords while the rest are normal input by users. So in the example .at & .from is keyword, so I want them individually. while "eat big mac", "East MacDonald", "onwards" are normal input and I need them too.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your keywords using special token (or delimiter) and then split using this delimiter:

```
String str = "eat big mac .at East MacDonald .from onwards";
String[] arr = str.replaceAll("(\\.\\w+)", "DELIMITER$1DELIMITER").split("DELIMITER");
```

This produces output:

`[eat big mac , .at,  East MacDonald , .from,  onwards]`

Answer (score 0):

You can always use split() method for each string you use.

```
String str = "eat big mac .at East MacDonald .from onwards";
String[] spaceDelimitedStr = str.split(" ");
String[] dotDelimitedStr = str.split("\\.");
String[] commaDelimitedStr = str.split(",");
```

and because the input to the split function is a regular expression you can provide all sorts of delimitations

For the result you are looking for its going to be very difficult to get what you want, can i ask why do you need this to be in the way it is?